# What is the header file for the uintptr_t type in modern C++?

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit, c99, stdint

I found that in C99 you should `#include <stdint.h>` and that seems to work with my C++03 gcc compiler too, but is that the right header for modern C++, is it portable?

Comment: `#include <cinttypes>` or `#include <cstdint>`

Comment: -1: for not bothering to look it up in the [easily searchable online references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: I think the objective is to have questions answered on stackoverflow, just because information can be Googled, does not mean a question is not worth having, or have I misunderstood the purpose of this site?

Comment: @WilliamKF: That is true, but at the same time, it is also true that you have not tried anything yourself. Just because you don't know something, doesn't mean that you *must* ask others, without *first* trying to find out the answer yourself. Asking others what you don't know, must not be programmers's habit. You must try yourself first.

Comment: But I did try it myself, I got my application to work and then posted the question *and* the answer that worked for me at the same time to help the next person.  I don't feel like I was being lazy but attempting to assist the next person.  Is my behavior really something to be discouraged?

Comment: @Nawaz respectfully, I believe there is evidence on this page contrary to what you say of WilliamKF and his motivations.

Comment: @WilliamKF: The question doesn't say anything about your efforts which you invested to find out the answer. Anyone reading your question would feel that you have not tried anything yourself.

Comment: I've updated the question to include what my efforts had revealed to be the answer.  Let me know if that is more in line with the expected style here, thanks!

Comment: @WilliamKF: It is still poor. I don't see any problem description which you face with what you found yourself.

Comment: @DrewDormann: I don't see any evidence. What evidence you're talking about?

Comment: @Nawaz The issue I faced was I wanted to use the `uintptr_t` type and needed the correct header file to include.  I found the answer to be `stdint.h`.  Perhaps this question should be deleted because it is not considered helpful to others?  My sense was that it would be helpful, but if others disagree then let's delete it.

Comment: @WilliamKF: You still didn't understand my point!

Comment: @Nawaz Sorry for being dense, please elaborate so I can better appreciate your point.

Comment: @Nawaz:  I'm sorry, but I do not wish to continue this.

Comment: @Nawaz: (and anyone) Feel free to continue the discussion here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145644

Comment: @WilliamKF: My previous comment says : *"I don't see any problem description which you face with what you found yourself"*. I think that tacitly asks you something.

Comment: Revision 6 of this question is quite acceptable as a SO question. Upvoted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In C++11, it's in `<cstdint>`.

In older versions of the language, it didn't officially exist; but many compilers provided the C99 library as an extension, in which case it would be available in `<stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, the standard header is in `cstdint`

```
#include <cstdint>
```

Answer (score 4):

It is defined in stdint.h:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Comment: That header exists for backwards-compatibility with C.  It _will_ define `uintptr_t` in the global namespace, but not `namespace std`.  You can expect all standard headers that end in `.h` to be namespace-unaware.

Comment: Thanks Drew, I had missed that.

Comment: @DrewDormann - they aren't necessarily unaware of namespaces. The standard C headers are required to put their names in the global namespace, and they are permitted to put them in `namespace std`. Similarly, the C++ analogs of the C headers are required to put their names into `namespace std` and are now allowed to put them in the global namespace, as well (that's a bow to existing implementations).

Answer (score 2):

Include either `cinttypes` or `cstdint`.

Comment: `<cinttypes>` doesn't define `uintptr_t`. Mostly it defined macros that can be used as format specifiers for the types defined in `<cstdint>` when using `printf` and `scanf` and their brethren.

Comment: @PeteBecker `<cinttypes>` includes `<cstdint>`

Answer (score 0):

It's in C99, in , as an optional type. Many C++03 compilers do provide that file. It's also in C++11, in , where again it is optional, and which refers to C99 for the definition. include stdint.h